# My computer is stuck at a lower resolution

Tags: windows, resolution

I play Team Fortress 2 in full-screen mode, with a lower-than-native resolution. Usually upon exiting the game Windows changes back to the native resolution. However, the other day I turned my computer on and the graphics were really large as if the screen was stuck at the lower resolution I play TF2 at. I tried restarting but that didn't help; I also googled the problem but nothing seemed to work. I have Windows 7 if that means anything.

Comment: Have you tried manually resetting your resolution to what it should be?

Comment: yeah, i had tried it, but nothing happen. :(

Comment: This question needs some computer jargon change.

Comment: I clarified the terminology a bit. @RawRCrew, if I made a mistake, feel free to edit your post, or click [here](http://superuser.com/posts/431429/revisions) and roll back to your original version. Also, we need some more information about your computer's hardware, as well as the resolution you normally use and the one you play TF2 at (which, I understand, is the resolution your computer is currently stuck at).

Comment: What is the current resolution? Is it 640x480 or 800x600? (I am thinking of the resolutions used by windows when there is a problem with the graphics driver and it falls back on its own VGA driver).

Comment: it's back to 800x600 , it's ussually changed automatically into best resolution after quit the game, but since a week ago, it not happened.

Comment: @RawRCrew What's your monitor's native resolution? Also, what exactly happens when you try manually set it to that resolution (as described in the answers below)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read this correct you want to return from the lower custom resolution used in TF2 to the normal full resolution.

Usually this is is done on windows 7 by either right clicking on a empty space on your desktop. At the bottom there will be an option named "screen resultion".  Left click on this to open a new window with screen settings.  Click on the drop down next to "Resolution" and select which resolution you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the desktop and choose "Screen resolution". From there, choose the resolution you want.

See also: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-your-screen-resolution